# Enable MSI on Intel PCI bridge

Tags: linux, drivers, pci-express

I'm using an HP Z400 Workstation with Linux kernel 4.9.20. I'm trying to enable MSI interrupts, however the PCI bridges seem to have MSI support disabled.

By using `lscpi -v` I can see something similar to this `Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable+ 64bit-` meaning that the MSI support is disabled.

This means that when I try to request more than 1 interrupt vector in my driver by doing something like this `ret = pci_alloc_irq_vectors(pci_dev, 2, max_irqs, PCI_IRQ_ALL_TYPES | PCI_IRQ_AFFINITY);` the function returns an error.

I've tested this same approach with different PCs and it works fine, and by using lspci I can see a different output: `Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-`

I've also upgraded the BIOS to the latest one provided by HP but I didn't notice anything different.

Does anyone has any idea of what could be causing this?

EDIT:

Here are the `lspci -vvv` outputs for two different bridges in the same PC (HP Z400)

```
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 13) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-00000fff
Memory behind bridge: fff00000-000fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
Capabilities: [90] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0
        ExtTag+ RBE+
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported-
        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
    DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
        ClockPM- Surprise+ LLActRep+ BwNot+ ASPMOptComp-
    LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x0, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug- Surprise-
        Slot #0, PowerLimit 0.000W; Interlock- NoCompl-
    SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
        Control: AttnInd Off, PwrInd Off, Power- Interlock-
    SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet- Interlock-
        Changed: MRL- PresDet- LinkState-
    RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible+
    RootCap: CRSVisible+
    RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
    DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range BCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported ARIFwd+
    DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 260ms to 900ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled ARIFwd-
    LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
    LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D3 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable+ DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
    UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
    CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ NonFatalErr+
    AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
Capabilities: [150 v1] Access Control Services
    ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
Capabilities: [160 v0] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=0 Len=00c <?>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp



00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 25
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
Memory behind bridge: f8000000-f80fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f7500000-00000000f76fffff
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
Capabilities: [40] Express (v1) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
        ExtTag- RBE+
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
    DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #6, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <4us
        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
    LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+
        Slot #0, PowerLimit 0.000W; Interlock- NoCompl-
    SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
        Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
    SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
        Changed: MRL- PresDet+ LinkState+
    RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
    RootCap: CRSVisible-
    RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Address: fee00000  Data: 40e1
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
    Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
    Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
    Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
    Status: InProgress-
    VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
Capabilities: [180 v1] Root Complex Link
    Desc:   PortNumber=06 ComponentID=02 EltType=Config
    Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=02 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
        Addr:   00000000fed1c000
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
```

Looking at the `lspci` output I can see that both use the same drivers, but one has MSI enabled and the other doesn't.

Answer: After some digging I found out that some Intel chipsets 5500, 5520 and X58 have issues with MSI and interrupt remapping, so BIOS vendors disabled it in firmware. [5500/5520 Errata](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/5520-and-5500-chipset-ioh-specification-update.pdf) [Novell KB](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7014344)

Comment: Is the local APIC enabled? (Look in `dmesg` for `ACPI: Local APIC` and `ACPI: LAPIC_NMI`). What does `/proc/interrupts` say? Are those bridges the root ports? Please include `lspci -v` output for at least one of those bridges, more if they differ.

Comment: Yes, APIC is enabled. The bridges are the root ports. I'll add the lspci output above.

Comment: Legacy Interrupts are also not disabled (`DisINTx-`), so I wonder if the BIOS insists on setting it up this way for some reason. Or maybe some setting in the BIOS that is hard to find?

Comment: I've looked around in the BIOS but I didn't find anything that looked useful. In another thread I found someone talked about enabling  VT-d but it was already enabled.

Comment: Looking around I found that Intel 5500 and 5520 chipsets have issues with  MSI https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/5520-and-5500-chipset-ioh-specification-update.pdf I suppose this is the cause for my issues

Comment: Please write this up as an answer, so the next person with a similar problem can find it. The comments may not be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found out that some Intel chipsets 5500, 5520 and X58 have issues with MSI and interrupt remapping, so BIOS vendors disabled it in firmware. [5500/5520 Errata](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/5520-and-5500-chipset-ioh-specification-update.pdf) [Novell KB](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7014344)